# Can't get Remote Desktop Services installed on Windows 2012 server

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

I am trying to install Remote Desktop Services on my dedicated Windows 2012 server but the installation does not start at all. It just stays here:

[image: Add Roles and Features Wizard]

I have tried restarting the server 2 times and I have run every Windows Update there is. I have tried selecting other features but it will not start the installation. I had it running for hours but it would not install at all (just as the screenshot) and I had to cancel it.

Can any one help me on how to get Remote Desktop Services installed somehow or another? Is there another way to get it installed? I am not in this case installing remotely.

Answer (score 0):

This guide to install via the Powershell seems to help: 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/manojnair/archive/2011/12/02/rds-powershell-tfm-part-i-installing-remote-desktop-role-services.aspx

Comment: Please explain, which steps are to be taken and refer to the link as the source. As of now, this does not really qualify as an answer